# Random enemy spawning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a game that uses the camera view, and has enemies flying around the screen. You then shoot the enemies using your chosen weapon. At the moment I have 4 UIImageView's, in which the enemies are animated. I am wanting to have multiple instances of each enemy (there are 4) on the screen, and with time more spawn. What is the best way to do this?

This is part of the code to move one enemy using the gyro: (enemyCyborg is the UIImageView)

```
valueX4 = gyroData.rotationRate.y* 30;
         valueY4 = gyroData.rotationRate.x* 40;

         int newX4 = (int)(enemyCyborg.center.x +valueY4);
         int newY4 = (int)(enemyCyborg.center.y -valueX4);

         CGPoint newCenter4 = CGPointMake(newX4, newY4);

         enemyCyborg.center = newCenter4;
```

And they are moving randomly within that:

```
- (void) moveCyborg {

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    int fromNumber = -30;
    int toNumber = 60;
    int randomNumber = (arc4random()%(toNumber-fromNumber))+fromNumber;
    //Move the image view to 100, 100 over 10 seconds.
    enemyCyborg.frame = CGRectMake((int)(enemyCyborg.center.x -randomNumber), (int)(enemyCyborg.center.y -randomNumber), enemyCyborg.frame.size.width, enemyCyborg.frame.size.height);
}];
}
```

This shows the UIImageView again, after it has been hidden from shooting it:

```
- (void) showCyborg {

enemyCyborg.hidden = NO;
enemyCyborg.center = CGPointMake((arc4random()%SCREEN_HEIGHT),(arc4random()%SCREEN_WIDTH));
enemyCyborg.animationImages  = cyborganim;
enemyCyborg.animationDuration = 0.6;
enemyCyborg.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[enemyCyborg startAnimating];

}
```

Comment: Your question seems a little vague.  Perhaps you could rephrase it by stating what you're having difficulty with?  Is it creating more views?  Representing more enemies?  Animating them all together?  Etc.

Comment: ... Yeah, I am not sure what you want. Just create a class that can be called to create multiple enemies. Objective-C is an Object-orientated language, so this is not hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create objects encapsulating the enemy model and spawn those objects using some kind of enemy generator function. This generator function might be a written as a class function.

Here are some general suggestions:

1) You're using the block-based animation methods. Blocks are a good approach but depending on your performance and the number of enemies and other visual elements you plan to add, you may want to look into using [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) which gives you all sorts of features. Ray Wenderlich has published a great intro to cocos2d tutorial that would get you up and running quickly. Link to that [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial). Many games for iPhone are written using either cocos2d or Unity.

2) Check in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ for further basic examples, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into that.